# calculate remaining years/days/hours/minutes/seconds from hours

Tags: javascript

Hi I was searching for a calculator that calculates from currenttime to output hours. I found a couple samples but they are working with dates or Unix times.

What I want is,

```
var output = "72:50:09",
    oneDay = "24:00:00",
    callculate = output / oneDay; //This must output 3 days

var checkRemaining = {
    calculateDiffrence: function() {
       var month,
           text;
       (callculate === 31) ? text = "1 month",
       (callculate === 62) ? text = "2 months",
       (callculate === 365) ? text = "1 year",
       return text;
    }
};
console.log(checkRemaining.calculateDiffrence);
```

Something like this, I couldn't think how to manage this the correct way.
I hope someone can help me a hand I'll appreciate that.

Calculate how many `years/days/hours/minutes/seconds` the `output` time have.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the number of days:

```
var output = "72:50:09",
oneDay = "24:00:00",
out = output.split(":").map(Number),
one = oneDay.split(":").map(Number),
callculate = out[0]/one[0]; //No of days
```

Now the `callculate` will hold the number of days.

```
var min = out[1]; //Will hold the minutes
var sec = out[2]; //Will hold the seconds 
var hrs = out[0]%one[0] //Will hold the hours
```

`Year/Months` is what you are calculating from your `function`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: all you need to do is check if the hour is less than 25. If it is then process the numbers (no Date/Time methods).

```
var output = "00:50:09",
    oneDay = "24:00:00";

var arr = output.split(":");
if (parseInt(arr[0], 10) < 25) {
    // if less than a day then just process numbers
    result = arr[0] + "hrs " + arr[1] + "min " + arr[2] + "sec";
} else {
    // more than 24 hrs so use the Date/Time methods
    var out = new Date(0, 0, 0, parseInt(arr[0], 10),
                                parseInt(arr[1], 10),
                                parseInt(arr[2], 10));
    console.log(out);

    var arr = oneDay.split(":");
    var one = new Date(0, 0, 0, parseInt(arr[0], 10),
                                parseInt(arr[1], 10),
                                parseInt(arr[2], 10));
    console.log(one);

    var dif = new Date(out - one);
    console.log(dif);

    var result = dif.getYear() - 70 + "yr " + 
                 dif.getMonth() + "mth " + 
                 dif.getDate() + "day " + 
                 dif.getHours() + "hrs " + 
                 dif.getMinutes() + "min " + 
                 dif.getSeconds() + "secs";
}
console.log(result);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pv0Lzcts/1/